# Como salvar imagem no banco de dados?

Tags: java, html, banco-de-dados, play-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicaçao web utilizando o play framework, no qual estou terminando de realizar o CRUD de um usuario, porem esta faltando somente a parte onde o usuario salva sua fotos de perfil no cadastro. COmo tenho pouca experiencia com web, estou com dificuldades em salvar a imagem do usuario e depois retorná-la na tela de listagem.

Essa é minha classe de cadastro:

```
public class Funcionarios extends Controller {

public static void form() { 
    long funcCount = Agente.count();
    System.out.println(funcCount);
    render(funcCount);
}

@AuditoriaOvitrampas
public static void cadastrar(@Valid Agente funcionario, String senha) throws Exception {

    Agente funcionarioBanco = Agente.find("email = ? or login = ?", funcionario.email, funcionario.login).first();

    if (funcionario.id == null) {
        if (funcionarioBanco != null && funcionarioBanco.id != funcionarioBanco.id && funcionarioBanco.foto == null) {
            validation.addError("funcionario.email", "E-mail já existente");
            validation.addError("funcionario.login", "Usuário já existente");
            validation.addError("funcionario.foto", "Imagem já cadastrada");
        }
        if (validation.hasErrors() || !funcionario.senha.equals(senha)) {
            validation.addError("funcionario.senha", "Senha não corresponde");
            params.flash();
            validation.keep();
            form();
        }
        funcionario.senha = Crypto.passwordHash(senha);
        validation.valid("cadastrado com sucesso");
        funcionario.save();
        session.get("usuarioLogado");
        listar(null);
    } else {
        validation.valid("editado com sucesso");
        funcionario.save();
        session.get("usuarioLogado");
        listar(null);

    }
}

public static void detalhesFuncionarios(Long id) {
    Agente f = Agente.findById(id);
    renderTemplate("Funcionarios/detalhesFuncionarios.html", f);
}
@AuditoriaOvitrampas
public static void editarFuncionarios(Long id) {
    Agente f = Agente.findById(id);
    renderTemplate("Funcionarios/form.html", f);
}

public static void listar(String parametroBusca) {
    List<Agente> funcionarios = null;
    if (parametroBusca == null) {
        funcionarios = Agente.find("status != ?", Status.INATIVO).fetch();          
    }
    render(funcionarios, parametroBusca);
}
@AuditoriaOvitrampas
public static void perfil(Long id){
    String perfil = session.get("usuarioLogado");
    Agente f = Agente.find("login = ?", perfil).first();
    renderTemplate("Funcionarios/perfil.html", f);
}
@AuditoriaOvitrampas
public static void removerFuncionarios(Long id) {
    Agente funcionario = Agente.findById(id);

    if(funcionario.email.equals("admin@admin.com")){
        validation.addError("funcionario.email", "E-mail já existente");
        listar(null);
    }
    funcionario.status = Status.INATIVO;
    funcionario.save();
    flash.success("Removido com sucesso");
    listar(null);
}

public static void formTrocarSenha() {
    render();
}

public static void trocarSenha(String senhaAtual, String novaSenha1, String novaSenha2){
    String senha = session.get("usuarioSenha");
    if(senha.equals(Crypto.passwordHash(senhaAtual))){
        if(novaSenha1.equals(novaSenha2)) {
            Agente f = Agente.findById(Long.parseLong(session.get("usuarioId")));
            f.senha = Crypto.passwordHash(novaSenha1);
            f.save();
            session.put("usuarioSenha", f.senha);
            renderTemplate("Funcionarios/perfil.html", f);
            flash.success("Senha alterada com sucesso!");
        }
        else{
            flash.error("Senhas não são iguais");
            renderTemplate("Funcionarios/formTrocarSenha.html");

        }
    } else {
        flash.error("Senha atual não corresponde a senha do usuário");
        renderTemplate("Funcionarios/formTrocarSenha.html");

    }
}
}
```

Meu model:

```
@Entity
public class Agente extends Model{
@Required
public String nome;
@Required
public String funcao;
@Required
@MinSize(6)
public String login;
@MinSize(6)
@MaxSize(15)
public String senha;
@Required
@Email
public String email;
public Blob foto;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="agente")
public List<Palheta> palhetas;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

public Agente() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
}
```

E meu formulario HTML:

```
<section class="forms">
<form action="@{funcionarios.cadastrar}" method="post">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="hidden" name="funcionario.id" value="${f?.id}" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nome completo:</label> <input type="text"
                        name="funcionario.nome" class="form-control"
                        value="${flash['funcionario.nome'] ? flash['funcionario.nome'] : f?.nome}">
                    <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.nome' /}</span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email:</label> <input type="email" name="funcionario.email"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="exemplo@dominio.com"
                        value="${flash['funcionario.email'] ? flash['funcionario.email'] : f?.email}">
                    <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.email' /}</span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Função:</label> <select name="funcionario.funcao"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="${flash['funcionario.funcao'] ? flash['funcionario.funcao'] : f?.funcao}">
                        <option>Agente de Endemias</option>
                        <option>Laboratorista</option>
                    </select> <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.funcao' /}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Adicionar foto do perfil:</label> <input type="file"
                        name="funcionario.foto" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                #{if f}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Matrícula:</label> <input id="loginUsuario" type="text"
                        placeholder="Mínimo 5 caracteres" name="funcionario.login"
                        class="form-control" disabled="disabled"
                        value="${flash['funcionario.login'] ? flash['funcionario.login'] : f?.login}">
                    <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.login' /}</span>
                </div>
                #{/if} #{ifnot f}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Matrícula:</label> <input id="loginUsuario" type="text"
                        placeholder="Mínimo 5 caracteres" name="funcionario.login"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="${flash['funcionario.login'] ? flash['funcionario.login'] : f?.login}">
                    <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.login' /}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Senha:</label> <input type="password"
                        name="funcionario.senha" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres"
                        value="${flash['funcionario.senha'] ? flash['funcionario.senha'] : f?.senha}">
                    <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.senha' /}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Confirmar senha:</label> <input type="password"
                        placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres" name="senha"
                        class="form-control"> <span class="alert-danger">#{error
                        'senha' /}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            #{/ifnot}
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"
                    onclick="window.location.href='/funcionarios/listar';">
                    Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não conheço a framework, mas procura sobre tipo de dado LOB ou BLOB no seu banco de dados,

Comment: Voce sabe fazer em java? acho q se me der uma dica em java posso desenrolar o restante, eh q nao tenho menor ideia de como começar.

Comment: Preciso saber se o banco de dados é um básico tipo MYSQL ou a framework possui seu próprio tipo de banco?

Comment: Por enquanto estou utilizando o proprio banco do play o H2, que eh um banco local.

Comment: Um exemplo em PHP, eu utilizou um comando para "serializar" qualquer objeto/imagem/array em "string", depois salvo ela no banco como formato "LOB" (Para textos grandes), depois na hora de recuperar eu apenas dou um "deserializar" na string transformando em objeto. Eu sei que no java tem a interface "Serializable" para isso, mas eu só trabalhei com arquivo local

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145713/does-h2-support-the-serializable-isolation-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um banco mongo para as imagens e salvar a imagem usando o mongo docker. É bastante simples. E no seu banco principal você salva o id que referencia a imagem no mongo.